# How to host a web service in localhost:6543

Tags: php, web-services

I building a web service in php and the server side is in localhost/demo/server.php.
I want it to be hosted in localhost:6543/demo/server.
do i need to open a socket in the server side or sometheing else?
Thanks.

Comment: You can tell web-server (any of those available including PHP dev server) which port to listen. The technique to do that varies from server to server so you should first decide which web-server to use.

Comment: im writing a SOAP web service so i am using soap_server from the nusoap library, how can i tell him in php to listen to port 6543 ?

Comment: Please provide the link to the library you are using.

Comment: @zstate     --- https://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

Comment: i dont sure i tagged right , please help @zstate

Comment: if you know to do this is in regular soapserver and soapclient that php offer it will be helpful too , @zstate

Comment: I think you are mixing 2 different things here the actual web server (might be apache, nginx, etc. ) and the `nusoap_server` php class from this library which acts like a controller to the soap request. In order to do what you want you need to find out what web server you are using. If you saying localhost is working then try to find who is listening on port `80`. Very likely it is apache or nginx.

Comment: I am using WAMP so I think it apache, if i change the listening port from 80 to 6453 so what i want will work ?, and if i will transfer the files to other computer its still work like i want or i will need to change it again ?  -  @zstate

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you need to change the listening port. However when you move you files to another computer or server you need to configure it again, but you do that only once when you setup the Apache server.